# Ant custom condition typedef: ensuring compiled class is available during build (chicken and egg)

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I have created a couple of [Custom Conditions](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/custom-programming.html#customconditions) for use in the build process of my project. The details are probably not very relevant, but they have very little logic and are used to conditionally suppress the running of the `ivy:resolve` task (whether or not this is a good idea is a separate question, but for my project this takes adds 12 seconds to the build process even to just read the cache).

The problem I have is that the first time the project is built, the implementation of these conditions (which right now lives in the main source tree of the project using them) is not available. In this case, I want to run `<ivy:resolve>` anyway, so that I can get the project (including the `condition` implementations) built completely, and then the `condition` implementations will be available for later use.

I've attempted to achieve this by hoping the `or` condition works lazily and making use of the `available` element within there:

```
<typedef onerror="report" name="olderormissing" classname="myproject.buildutils.FileOlderOrMissingCondition" classpath="${main.jar}" />
<condition property="ivy.needs.refresh">
    <or>
        <!-- fetch new if we don't have the helper classes -->
        <not><available classname="myproject.buildutils.FileOlderOrMissingCondition" /></not>
        <!-- only fetch ivy deps hourly -->
        <olderormissing file="${ivy.build.record}" threshold="3600" />
    </or>
</condition>

<!-- Ivy task using the above property -->
<target name="resolve" description="--> retrieve dependencies with ivy" if="${ivy.needs.refresh}">
    <ivy:retrieve symlink="true" sync="false" pattern="${jars.dir}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]" keep="true" log="download-only" />
</target>
```

I had hoped that if implementation class was not available, the `or` condition would spit out true from the first condition and ignore the missing types. However, this doesn't work, instead failing with "or doesn't support the nested "olderormissing" element." Perhaps this approach is going to be futile?

Ideally I'd want Ant to handle this without needing to split the condition implementations into a separate or sub-project requiring explicit manual pre-compilation (If I could make Ant compile the subproject automatically though, that would be great, but I can't see a way to make that happen early enough to be available for the require `typedef`). A separate project definitely feels like overkill for the two lines of logic implemented in the classes.

[This related question on taskdefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093784/ant-check-classpath-for-jar-before-taskdef) seems relevant but doesn't exactly work for this use case, AFAICT.

Comment: I have just discovered the Ant `typefound` task, which seems like a perfect fit for this kind of thing (better than using `available` above), but it still has the same problem. I guess in general my question could be rephrased as "How can I use `typefound` in general as a build condition?" Subsequent XML seems to still require the presence of the type we're conditionally evaluating, so I can't see how to make this useful.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve. Ivy uses a cache to avoid repeated downloads of the same files. This feature is built in, you don't need to layer this logic on top.

Comment: True, but Ivy is *slow* at even reading the cache for some reason. The dependency set of the project is fairly large. Builds are taking 12 seconds when I run `ivy:resolve`, but 300 ms when I don't. 12 seconds may not be that much time, but it seems like a silly way to sit around waiting for the build to finish when it could be done so much quicker (I may have Ivy set up incorrectly though, but it's not spending its time downloading). In any case, the more general problem here of how to actually make use of `typedef`s in the buiold process before building is done has a more general application.

Comment: It used to cost also some time to resolve and this can be slightly optimized.
However, I'm always against hacks to optimize code, this is way harder to sustain than at first site.
Try using the modules tag in ivysettings to optimize your resolution  decision.
    <modules>
        <!-- For artifacts expected to change -->
 <module revision=".*SNAPSHOT.*" matcher="regexp" resolver="local"/>
.
.
.
and so forth.

Comment: We'll see. So far, updating Ivy hourly and when `ivy.xml` changes has worked fine. I promise to post back here if I find out otherwise though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got a few clues from the [Ant taskdef tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html). The `typedef`s and `condition`s can be better used within a target which sets the appropriate property, but which is only called when the precursor classes are set up. And we can set up a special bootstrapping target to run `javac` only on the relevant Ant extension classes. We also need to make the actual retrieving/resolving happen in a separate task, so we can force it to happen independent of the value of the conditions.

```
<condition property="ant.extensions.missing">
    <not>
        <available classname="readproject.ant.FileOlderOrMissingCondition" classpath="${main.jar}" />
    </not>
</condition>

<target name="ant-bootstrapping" depends="init" if="ant.extensions.missing" description="(internal) build the project-internal Ant extensions if needed">
    <antcall target="force-resolve" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpathref="build.classpath" includeantruntime="false" includes="**/ant/**/*.java" debug="on"/>
</target>


<!-- need to set up the conditions internally, since the custom types are defined in the project itself -->
<target name="pre-resolve" depends="ant-bootstrapping" description="(internal) set up internal variables to determine if Ivy needs refreshing">
    <typedef onerror="report" name="olderormissing" classname="myproject.ant.FileOlderOrMissingCondition" classpath="${build}" />
    <condition property="ivy.needs.refresh">
        <!-- only fetch ivy deps hourly -->
        <olderormissing file="${ivy.build.record}" threshold="3600" />
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="resolve" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy" if="ivy.needs.refresh" depends="pre-resolve">
    <antcall target="force-resolve" />
</target>

<target name="force-resolve" description="Force retrieval of Ivy dependencies">
    <ivy:retrieve symlink="true" sync="false" pattern="${jars.dir}/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]" keep="true" log="download-only" />
    <ivy:report todir="${ivy.reports}" />
    <touch file="${ivy.build.record}" />
</target>
```

My main compile target then depends on the `resolve` target, as before, and everything builds satisfactorily whether on a clean install or a refresh, but Ivy doesn't make my build time 24 times slower unnecessarily.

(I should also note that I'm using `available` here instead of `typefound` since the latter doesn't allow me to specify the classpath, so is not much use)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use ivy to populate a lib directory and then only run ivy to populate it.

```
<available file="lib" type="dir" property="local.lib.present"/>

<target name="resolve" unless="local.lib.present">
    <ivy:retrieve symlink="true" pattern="lib/[conf]/[artifact].[ext]"/>
</target>

..

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
    <delete dir="lib"/>
    <ivy:clean-cache/>
</target>
```

It's important to have a "clean-all" target that purges all caches and enabling a clean build.

I see you're using the symlink option which addresses possible concerns regarding the space consumed by this local build caching approach.

Comment: That is a simpler and probably more robust solution than mine, although it doesn't have the advantage of automatically forcing an Ivy refresh in some configurable time frame, or when (more usefully) I add a dependency to `ivy.xml` -- these will need to manually managed by running 'clean-all', as you note. Which is probably not that hard, but I've sunk all that time into my arguably over-engineered solution which requires marginally less manual management...